# AWS - elastic load balancer unable to handle the request

Tags: domain-name-system, amazon-web-services, load-balancing

I'm totally new to **AWS and the world**. My problem here is while requesting to AWS server.
I have a server `staging-storage.zazzercode.co` pointing to following `DNS's` with respective load balancers,

```
s-storage-us-west-2-483191837.us-west-2.elb.amazonaws.com => s-storage-us-west-2
s-storage-us-east-1-1318227839.us-east-1.elb.amazonaws.com => s-storage-us-east-1
```

I live in [Eastern world](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eastern_world).

#### Point 0

I upgraded instance sizes from `t1.micro` to `m3.medium` hoping it would get fixed.

#### Point 1

While requesting to the server using hostname `'staging-storage.zazzercode.co'`, I get following error in a `curl` request,

```
curl: (6) Couldn't resolve host 'staging-storage.zazzercode.co'
```

According to `man curl`, `6` is,

```
6      Couldn't resolve host. The given remote host was not resolved.
```

#### Point 2

It sometimes tells me

```
HTTP/1.1 100 Continue

HTTP/1.1 504 Gateway Timeout
Content-length:0
```

Which is documented here - [Troubleshooting Elastic Load Balancing: Error Messages](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ElasticLoadBalancing/latest/DeveloperGuide/ts-elb-error-message.html) suggesting

1. Insufficient capacity in the Load Balancer to handle the request.(transient issue)
2. instance closing the connection to ELB.

#### Point 3

It responds with proper response after few attempts. Others of my team face the same issue.

#### Point 4

When I ping the hostname, It hangs

```
$ ping staging-storage.zazzercode.co
PING s-storage-us-west-2-483191837.us-west-2.elb.amazonaws.com (54.199.188.111) 56(84) bytes of data.
```

#### Point 5

I can properly `ssh` the both of the instances.

#### Point 6

`nslookup` on `zazzercode.co` gives me,

```
$ nslookup -type=NS zazzercode.co
Server:     127.0.1.1
Address:    127.0.1.1#53

Non-authoritative answer:
zazzercode.co   nameserver = ns-1605.awsdns-08.co.uk.
zazzercode.co   nameserver = ns-1302.awsdns-34.org.
zazzercode.co   nameserver = ns-510.awsdns-63.com.
zazzercode.co   nameserver = ns-692.awsdns-22.net.

Authoritative answers can be found from:
```

`nslookup` on `staging-storage.zazzercode.co` gives me,

```
$ nslookup -q=NS staging-storage.zazzercode.co
Server:     127.0.1.1
Address:    127.0.1.1#53

Non-authoritative answer:
staging-storage.zazzercode.co   canonical name = s-storage-us-west-2-483191837.us-west-2.elb.amazonaws.com.

Authoritative answers can be found from:
us-west-2.elb.amazonaws.com
    origin = ns-332.awsdns-41.com
    mail addr = awsdns-hostmaster.amazon.com
    serial = 1
    refresh = 7200
    retry = 900
    expire = 1209600
    minimum = 60
```

#### Point 7

[Digging `zazzercode.co` gives me](http://sesblog.amazon.com/post/Tx3CTDG8N8GTE3G/How-to-check-your-domain-verification-settings),

```
$ dig TXT  ns-692.awsdns-22.net _amazonses.zazzercode.co

; <<>> DiG 9.9.2-P1 <<>> TXT ns-692.awsdns-22.net _amazonses.zazzercode.co
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: SERVFAIL, id: 33984
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 0, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 1

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 4096
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;ns-692.awsdns-22.net.      IN  TXT

;; Query time: 46 msec
;; SERVER: 127.0.1.1#53(127.0.1.1)
;; WHEN: Thu Jul 24 11:54:31 2014
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 49

;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NXDOMAIN, id: 30277
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 0, AUTHORITY: 1, ADDITIONAL: 1

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 4096
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;_amazonses.zazzercode.co.  IN  TXT

;; AUTHORITY SECTION:
zazzercode.co.      900 IN  SOA ns-692.awsdns-22.net. awsdns-hostmaster.amazon.com. 1 7200 900 1209600 86400

;; Query time: 173 msec
;; SERVER: 127.0.1.1#53(127.0.1.1)
;; WHEN: Thu Jul 24 11:54:31 2014
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 137
```

I suspect it to be **LoadBalancer** issue. Is there a way to check if **LoadBalancer** is dropping the connection? Or What could be the issue here?

I'll put further details if needed.

(`zazzercode.co` is imaginary name here to hide the actual name till this point,actual is `soothsayer.co` everything else remaining the same)

### References

[Issues with EC2 Elastic Load Balancer DNS and routing](https://serverfault.com/a/531662/113713)

Comment: "(zazzercode is imaginary name here to hide the actual name at the moment)" This eliminates some of the most basic troubleshooting steps we can do.

Comment: Point 1 indicates a DNS issue. Is DNS hosted on the instances themselves? If they get bogged down, they're both going to do the timeouts in Point 2 and not answer DNS queries reliably, leading to Point 1 as well. Point 4 is not relevant unless you've opened ICMP ping in the AWS security groups for the ELB.

Comment: @ceejayoz The actual name is `soothsayer.co` instead of `zazzercode.com`. My first attempt on these things. Trying to get it work.

Comment: Are you using internal DNS of some sort? `staging-backend.soothsayer.co` doesn't appear to have public DNS entries.

Comment: @ceejayoz Question is amended to look everything real. It's `staging-storage.soothsayer.co` btw.